# In Snowflake which interfaces can be used to create and/or manage Virtual Warehouses?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

A. The Snowflake Web Interface (UI)
B. SQL commands
C. Data integration tools

Do Data Integration tools used for creating Virtual Warehouse. "A" and "B" are correct but for "C" I am little bit confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be studying for the SnowPro certification, and this is one of the "practice questions" ?

I think a little care might be needed with this one. Snowflake do put a few "trick" questions in these exams.

So, some data integration tools can create and manage Snowflake virtual warehouses. The answer by @MichaelGolos includes a link to PDI's documention:

> In PDI, you can create, modify, and even delete a Snowflake virtual warehouse to help you automate your virtual warehouse scaling activities. These orchestration entries include:

> Create Snowflake warehouse
> You can use this job entry to create a Snowflake virtual warehouse. You can set size, scaling, automated suspension, and other properties for your warehouse.

> Modify Snowflake warehouse
> Once you create a warehouse, you can edit its settings using this job entry. Modifying a warehouse is useful if your users typically perform simple queries and only require a small warehouse. However, to meet your ETL service-level agreements (SLA), you may need a larger warehouse during the ETL process. Using this job entry, you can modify the warehouse at the beginning of the ETL process to scale it up, and then modify it to scale it back down when the ETL process is complete.

> Delete Snowflake warehouse
> Use this job entry to delete virtual warehouses. Deleting unwanted virtual warehouses helps you clean up the Snowflake management console.

HOWEVER, pay careful attention to the wording of this question:

> **In Snowflake** which interfaces can be used to create and/or manage Virtual Warehouses?

where I have added **bold** emphasis.

The kind of orchestration that PDI and other tools provide is not **In Snowflake** - it is a 3rd party tool, and therefore is outside Snowflake. So, in my opinion the answer to this question is NO.

Comment: Hi Robert...Thank you for your valuable input...Just want to clarify that "In Snowflake" at the start has been added by me additionally. When in question it says "Data Integration tools" that itself means they are referring to 3rd Party tool and if we have an additional option of " All of the above"  then I think we need to consider Data Intergration Tool  as well and "All of the above" will become the correct answer. Hope you agree with me.

Comment: Without seeing the exact wording I can't really comment, but if you are hoping to get good answers to questions like this, it is important that you don't change the question !!

Comment: Which interfaces can be used to create and/or manage Virtual Warehouses?
A. The Snowflake Web Interface (UI)
B. SQL commands
C. Data integration tools
D. All of the above

Comment: Personally I think the question is ambiguous. On the one hand it's an exam about how to use Snowflake - not how to use 3rd party tools, therefore the question should mean "within snowflake", in which case the answer is NO. On the other hand, if the question means "using either Snowflake directly or with 3rd party tools" then the answer is YES. Unfortunately, with the way the question is worded, it is not clear. I wonder if this question comes from an *actual* exam, or from one of the "training" sites where they make up their own questions.

Comment: Anyways ..Thanks if it does come also then I know the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there are integration tools that support the management of Virtual Data Warehouses.
One example might be Pentaho, please see this article in Hitachi documentation: [PDI and Snowflake](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.1/Products/PDI_and_Snowflake)

Comment: Thanks MIchael..Just need to clarify do Data integration tools also supports creation of Virtual Warehouse?

Comment: Yes, please read the description from the link: https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/9.1/Products/Create_Snowflake_warehouse

Answer (score 1):

I’m not entirely sure what the actual question is that you are asking but…

Could a data integration tool manage warehouses? Yes

Do some data integration tools actually do this? Yes

Do all data integration tools do this? No

Comment: Thanks Nickw....Can you also let me know if Data Integration tools not all but some of them do support creation of virtual warehouse also?